What are the hole dimensions for 0.1" pitch headers?
What are the hole dimensions for 0.1" pitch headers?
As discussed in How to breadboard with large lead components (such as TO-220)?, holes on standard 0.1" pitch headers are:

Rectangular (not square or circular!)
Accommodate large leads, such as TO-220, in one orientation, but not the other
Don't seem to be documented (not as a standard and not on any manufacturer data sheets I've found)

All 3 of those properties apply to breadboard sockets as well.
What are the hole dimensions? Either as a standard or as a representative component from a vendor.

Clarification
To clarify, my question is not about the dimensions of the pins connecting the header to the board.  Rather, I'm asking about the dimensions of the receptacle where the component connects to the header.

Before pursuing this further, use some pliers to pull out a pin from the header to look at how the mating contact works.

Rectangular (not square or circular!) ... are you talking about holes in a PCB?

@jsotola I'm talking about the holes in a female header.  Holes in solderless breadboards are also rectangular (not square or circular).

@SRobertJames I've never seen a breadboard with rectangular holes ... I've seen square and round holes

@jsotola I think they mean that the maximum pin size they can accept without damage is rectangular, even if the hole itself is square (because they just have two tines that wipe along the pin). This is true of most breadboards, at least; machined-pin headers have a round maximal pin, and some high-current contacts are designed to make contact with all four sides of a square pin.

For less standard machined-pin headers from companies like preci-dip or mill-max, you can get the information fairly easily--for instance, mill-max's 801 series headers (which accept standard 25 mil square pins, or round pins from 25 to 37 mils in diameter) specify that they use their #47 contact, which you can then find not only dimensions for, but even insertion and removal force specifications.

Image taken from this datasheet.
For industry-standard 100-mil headers, this isn't information that's all that easy to find; they usually just specify that the header will mate with a standard 25 mil square pin. I was able to find this specification for a 2-pin jumper from Amphenol:

Image from this datasheet
I've not been able to find any such information from other sources, however, and there's no guarantee the dimensions of the jumper will match the dimensions of standard headers in the series. It's possible you may be able to rely on 3D models provided by companies that tend to have pretty accurate 3D models, like Samtec, but I can't say with any certainty.

0.1" (2.54mm) pitch headers are designed to be soldered into a PCB. One standard (there are others, such as those with round screw-machine pins) has 0.025" (0.635mm) square pins.
A typical recommended PCB hole diameter is 1.1mm round. For hand assembly this is very loose, but it does account for almost any imaginable build up of tolerances and for machine insertion. The diagonal dimension of a 0.64mm pin is about 0.9mm and the corners are not exactly square, and would only contact the hole at the corners anyway, so you can certainly get away with 0.9mm for short runs of 4 or 5 pins, and 1mm is quite loose.

Thank you.  Can you see clarification in revised OP that I'm asking about the dimensions of the receptacle for the component?

One end is intended to go into a PCB and be soldered, and that is one “receptacle” and the other goes into a female socket which either accepts a crimped wire terminal or is also soldered into a PCB. The dimensions of the hole in the molding are not generally given to users (they would be on internal drawings) because they are of no interest when the header & socket are used as intended.

The size and dimensions of the chamfered lead-in are designed to accommodate manufacturing tolerances, variations in resin shrinkage, etc so would be bigger than the 0.025” pin dimensions.

"0.1" pitch headers" is vague, as there are literally 100's of different PCB headers with a 2.54 mm pitch. So let's pick one as an example.
A popular one is a shroudless pin header. The size of its square pins is 0.025 inch = 0.635 mm. The diagonal is 0.9 mm = 0.035 inch. Therefore, a 0.045 inch / 1.1 mm diameter PCB hole will work fine.

Accommodate large leads, such as TO-220, in one orientation, but not the other

Here are some: https://www.digikey.com/short/ppqjz22q
Let's pick this one: Sullins TCC05DCSN-S1403, https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/sullins-connector-solutions/TCC05DCSN-S1403/4213430

{Source: Digikey}
The pins are in a 0.1 inch grid, perfect for a breadboard. The size is 0.025 inch, so it will fit fine in a breadboard.

I've used that Sullins part before. As a caveat, one annoyance about it is that the holes on top are just slightly out of tolerance to fit a TO-247-4 in without deforming the leads. (three-lead TO-247s fit just fine, though).

Thank you.  Can you see clarification in revised OP that I'm asking about the dimensions of the receptacle for the component? The holes seem to be 0.05" wide, which is the same size as a TO-220 lead (ignoring tolerance) - will it fit?

"the dimensions of the receptacle for the component" -- The component is a TO220 socket. That tell me all I need to know: it's the right dimensions for a TO 200 component. I don't need to know the actual dimensions. In any case, the dimensions are not fixed because they are spring leaves.

@DavideAndrea I know you mean TO-220, but just to note: this socket would not be suitable for a TO-200 part.
